# Homotopy type of space of continuous vs algebraic functions on complex varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Given a finite type scheme over $\mathbb{C}$ like $\text{Spec}(A)$. What is the homotopy type of space of continuous fucntions on the complex points of $\text{Spec}(A)$? (With compact open topology).

What is the homotopy type of subspace of regular functions i.e. $A$? and how does that compare to the continuous ones.

P.S. By Stone-Weierstrass the regular functions are dense in continuous functions with the compact-open topology, but I am not sure how their homotopy types compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both spaces are contractible. In this case the compact-open topology is the topology of compact convergence, and we can simply define the homotopy $H(t,f)=tf$ which contracts both spaces down to a point.

Comment: I made a mistake. What I wrote does not require connectedness since functions on disconnected spaces are just tuples of functions on each component.